\mathaccent syntax and font encoding
I am wondering how exactly \mathaccent is working in conjunction with the font encoding.
In The Latex2e Sources Chapter 6.4.8 'Math accents' the declaration is simply done using the OT1 encoding with two hex values.
I had however this problem (issue due to font encoding, T1 vs. OT1) and I am wondering how to solve analogous problems for, for example, the ¨ character.
The solution for the dieresis can actually be found in another post but I don't fully understand the solution:
I guess " marks that the following is a hex value. The last two values indicate the character position on the encoding table.
What do the first two values do though?
Another point of confusion for me is the accents package. In its .sty file lines 82-92 are the appropriate values for the accents. Taking that as a references, the point about the last two hex values being the encoding position does not seem to be correct as both the tilde and vec have the same last two values.
Any help in figuring out the syntax is appreciated.
For backtracking convenience on encoding tables: OT1 encoding table, T1 encoding table (both Wikipedia), LaTeX Project's font encoding guide

\mathaccent is a tex primitive that takes a single (15-bit) number although that number is usually given as a hex (" prefixed) number as it makes decoding the number easier.
\mathaccent "cfxx

so

the single hex digit c (usually 0 or 7) specifies the math class
The single hex digit f specifies the \fam
The two hex digits xx specify the character position.

so plain TeX defines for example \acute as
\def\acute{\mathaccent"7013 }

and the latex definition is equivalent.
so it is class 7 (\mathalpha in latex) so follows the local font setting such as \mathbf
It comes from \fam 0 by default (which is the \textrm font). In plain TeX and LaTex this is OT1 encoded by default.
It takes position hex 13 from the specified font.
If you do not use OT1 encoded fonts for fam 0 in latex you need to redefine all the accent commands as they are defined assuming this encoding.
the laTeX definition of \acute in the format is
\DeclareMathAccent{\acute}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"13}

Which is the same as the primitive definition, but using symbolic names \mathalpha for 7 and operators for 0
